# MockAggregator - TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: solidity, python

I'm setting up MockV3Aggregator and when trying to run brownie run scripts/deploy.py I'm hit with 'NoneType' is not iterable.

```
from brownie import FundMe, MockV3Aggregator, network, config
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account


def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    
    if network.show_active() != "development":
        price_feed_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()][
            "eth_usd_price_feed"
        ]
    else:
        print(f"The active netowrk is {network.show_active()}")
        print("Deploying Mocks...")
        mock_aggregator = MockV3Aggregator.deploy(
            18, 2000000000000000000000, {"from": account}
        )
        price_feed_address = mock_aggregator.address
        print("Mocks Deployed!")

    fund_me = FundMe.deploy(
        price_feed_address,
        {"from": account},
        publish_source=config["networks"][network.show_active()].get("verify"),
    )
    print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")


def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

Prior to setting up the else statement, it was working fine. Any help would be great if you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `brownie-config.yaml` file and make sure there are no empty fields or unnecessary indentation. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was solved by removing a empty line at the end of the brownie-config.yaml